# CSS Zoom does not work iPad OS (v13- latest) Safari

Tags: ipad, safari, zoom, ipados, css

I have discovered a bug in Safari with iPad OS. The problem is that when I zoom using the css zoom attribute, safari is taking an element's font-size and is either enlarging or shrinking based on the zoom level.

Example: If I have an element with font-size: 20px at 100% and zoom to 50%, safari is making the font-size now 40px keeping the element at 100% therefore breaking my layout. This only occurs only on devices running iPad OS. (This happens at all zoom levels 50%, 60%, 70%, etc.)

Does anyone have any extra information on iPad OS that may help me solve this problem? I have already reported to Apple, but it has been a while since I have had any status update.

LINK TO TEST: http://alleetest.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 1):

I see your issue. Unfortunately, I have noticed that Apple has broken several aspects of webpage rendering on iPadOS, leaving several minor visual quirks that didn't exist in Safari 12 for iPad.

Although it is very annoying that they broke Safari, unfortunately, we have to live with it in the meantime. What I would do is create a script that will increase and decrease the size of the elements, text, borders, etc. when you change the "zoom" size. Doing this would also give support for the Firefox browser, as it doesn't have support for the CSS zoom.

This suggestion might not be ideal, depending on what you are trying to do, but hopefully, this helps somewhat.

Also, it should be noted that the iPadOS Safari browser's built-in zoom feature using a keyboard will work correctly, just not the CSS zoom.

Comment: thank you for you confirmation. I have wrote a script that does as what you have described, unfortunately I have some pages with numerous and nested elements therefore slowing down the rendering of the page. 

I have contacted Apple support about this issue, and have not received any response on if this will be fixed or if I need to just use my workaround for this.

Comment: I would file the bug at https://bugs.webkit.org/ as I didn't see it listed there (unless I just didn't find it). it will most likely get better attention there than Apple Support.

Comment: Awesome, I created a report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206550

Comment: @leroyjenkinss24, does the issue still exist?

Comment: @RikeshSubedi For me the issue still exists on iPadOS. They have not fixed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function setTransformScale(scaleFactor) {
    if(!scaleFactor) scaleFactor = 1;

    let height = $(window).height()*(1/scaleFactor);
    let width = $(window).width()*(1/scaleFactor);

    $(".body-container").css({
        width: width+"px",
        height: height+"px",
        transform: `scale(${scaleFactor})`
    });
};
```

I have completely removed the CSS Zoom property from my site and switched to transform: scale() property. To counter the spacing I added "transform-origin: top left" to my css file and in javascript I run my created function when sizing pages.

$(".body-container") is my div element right below the body tag causing the zoom effect on my entire page.

Comment: How does removing CSS Zoom effect from *your* website address the issue of CSS Zoom not working on the iPad with iOS v13.x.  This seems it will only work in one very specific scenario.

Comment: The issue with the actual CSS Zoom on iPad OS remains. Due to lack of response from apple, I had to come up with my own solution (described above). This solution produces the same results as if CSS Zoom still worked accordingly.